# missing man pages of some commands

Tags: man, documentation, shell-builtin

Typing `man alias` gives me

> No manual entry for alias

The same thing goes for `export` and `eval`. At first I thought it only happens to shell built-in commands but `man echo` gives me the man page.

Except for googling, is there a way that I can view the documentation of those commands? If not, is there a way to "install" those missing man pages?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167004/ .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have the man page for `echo` because most systems have an `echo` binary in `/bin`, even though most shells provide a built-in anyway; you're seeing the man page for that binary. The man pages for all the other commands you're missing are in the POSIX Programmer's Manual (man section 1P). How to install it will depend on your distro; on Gentoo they're in the `sys-apps/man-pages-posix` package

Comment: on ubuntu it is in the `manpages-posix` package, and thanks for the bit about `/bin/echo` as well

Answer (score 5):

Builtin commands can be easily found by checking the man page of your current shell:

In the man page of bash, you'll find:

> ```
> alias [-p] [name[=value] ...]
>        Alias with no arguments or with the -p option prints the list of
>        aliases in the form alias name=value on standard output. When
>        arguments are supplied, an alias is defined for each name whose
>        value is given. A trailing space in  value causes the next word to
>        be checked for alias substitution when the alias is expanded. For
>        each name in the argument list for which no value is supplied, the
>        name and value of the alias is printed. Alias returns true  unless
>        a name is given for which no alias has been defined.
> ```

When in doubt, run `which alias` when it reports builtin, or it can't be found in `$PATH`, there's a good chance it's a builtin, so check the appropriate man pages.

Comment: You can also check using `type`.  eg, `type alias` returns `alias is a shell builtin`

Answer (score 3):

man information for built-in commands usually are available in the related shell man page. Try `man bash`.

Comment: for bash builtins you can also use `help export`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can get information about bash built-in commands with `help`, for example `help alias` or `help export`.

Comment: Good, and if you prefer the `man` format you can do `help -m`, like `help -m alias`

Answer (score 1):

`alias`, `export`, and `eval` are all part of `man builtin` on Mac OS X and, I assume, on other BSD systems.

On OS X, the man pages for the builtin commands are all aliased to builtin, so if I type `man alias` it will pull up `man builtin`. The problem though is that `man builtin` doesn't really provide information on the individual commands. Therefore, to get info on alias, you have to use `help alias`.

While I prefer reading man pages from a terminal prompt, if missing from a system, I'll go to http://man.cx/ as it's pretty comprehensive.