# How can I `man print`?

Tags: command-line, zsh, command, man, shell-builtin

Where can I find more information about the command(?) `print` since I don't receive a result when I input `man print`? For example, in the `zsh` I can do the following:

```
$ print "Hello, world\!"
Hello, world!
```

I've seen `print -P foo` and `print -n bar` used among other flags and have no idea what they mean nor do I know where to look for further information. So we have two questions really:

1. Where does `print` come from and where can I find documentation for it?
2. Where does one find documentation for similar items that are not to be found in the `man` pages?

NOTE: For clarification, I'm not trying to print a sheet of paper. I am also aware of `printf`, which allows for formatted output and has a man page.

Comment: What is `print`?

Comment: Can you please let everyone know whether you wanted print as in printing to a printer or the command `print` as in printing to the terminal?

Comment: rProblem with this question is that you have not indicated in what context you are looking for the command print.

Comment: Downvoters: while the question may not be a model of detail and backegound research, it is IMHO a valid and valuable entry-level question. The fact that it assumes things are simple when they are not is hardly the asker's fault. Unix printing should be at least as simple as on other platforms, in an ideal world.

Comment: @tripleee It probably got downvoted because nobody knows which "print" they're referring to and there's been no attempt at clarifying it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek (or rather @downvoters) As I write, vrtcl1dvoshun hasn't been back to the site yet, so he hasn't had an opportunity to clarify. I think that *printing* is meant in the layman sense. If it wasn't clear, the question should be closed as NaRQ, but there isn't a single close vote.

Comment: So you want the documentation of the shell builtin after all? Then your question would be a duplicate of [missing man pages of some commands](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1834/missing-man-pages-of-some-commands). Given that there are now two detailed answers about printing in the layman sense, I think the best course of action would be to edit this question to be about printing, but I'll edit something about `print` in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `zsh`, at the prompt, type `print`, and then <kbd>Alt-H</kbd>.

If it gives you the man page for the `print` system command instead of the `print` builtin, you may want to follow the instructions given under *Accessing On-Line Help* at:

```
info zsh Utilities
```

For `zsh` documentation, I prefer to use `info` in general. The `zsh` documentation is properly indexed and it's very easy to find documentation using `info`.

For instance to find the documentation for `print`, type `info zsh`, and within `info`, type <kbd>i</kbd> to bring up the index prompt and type `print` (you can throw in a couple of <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get a completion list). Or just run

```
info zsh print
```

To open the zsh info book and jump directly to the `print` index entry.

Answer (score 2):

### Documentation for the `print` command

`man print` only gives you information about a command called `print`. Unfortunately, the command to print a file is not called `print`.

Ksh and zsh have a built-in command `print`. Like all built-ins, they are documented [in the manual for the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1834/missing-man-pages-of-some-commands) (`man zshbuiltins` or the very long `man zshall` for zsh). You can tell that a command is built-in with `type`:

```
$ type print
print is a shell builtin
```

[`apropos print`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apropos_(Unix)) would show a list of commands whose description contains the word “print”; what you're looking for is in there, but buried inside a lot of other commands where “print” is used in the sense of “display text in the terminal”.

On Debian and derived distributions including Ubuntu, there is a command called `print`, which has a [man page](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=print&sektion=1). It is part of the [mime-support](http://packages.debian.org/mime-support) package, which also provides commands `see`, `edit` and `compose`. This package uses `/etc/mime.types` to determine the file's [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) from the file name extension and [`/etc/mailcap`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=mailcap&sektion=5) and `~/.mailcap` to determine which program to use.

On most Linux distributions, [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) plays a similar role to Debian's `edit`, but there is no analog for `print`.

### A primer on printing from the command line

Most unix installations these days use [CUPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS) for printing. This system originated on Mac OS X but is now dominant on Linux and present on other unix variants as well. CUPS is easiest to configure through its web interface at `http://localhost:631/`.

If the printer is already configured and you want to print, depending on your system, the command is either [`lp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lp) or [`lpr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lpr). The simplest form of the command is `lp myfile.ps` or `lpr myfile.pdf`; depending on which printing system your computer uses, these commands may support many options. Check the man page on your system for details. If you need to specify a printer name, it's `lp -d printername myfile.ps` or `lpr -Pprintername myfile.ps`.

The traditional file format for printing is [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript). Nowadays, most printing systems support [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) out of the box as well, and possibly other formats. I don't think there's an easy way to find out what input formats are supported, so I recommend converting your file to PS or PDF before printing (you'll have more control over layout options that way anyway).

You can see what files are currently being printed with the command [`lpstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lpstat-cups) or [`lpq`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lpq&sektion=1). This lets you know when your file has finished printing (or rather when it's been fully transmitted to the printer). This also tells gives you the job ID for your print job, which you can use to cancel the job with [`lprm`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lprm&sektion=1) or [`cancel`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cancel-cups). You can also see a list of available printers with `lpstat -a` or `lpq -a`.

If your system is using CUPS, another useful command is [`lpoptions`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lpoptions-cups). The command `lpoptions -l` lists printer options that you can use on the `lp` or `lpr` command lines; for example, with many duplex printers, `lp -o Duplex=DuplexNoTumble` prints double-sided.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `printf`. Since `printf` is a build in of your shell, you should look in the shell's man page, probably with `man bash` and search for `printf`

Comment: Wonder if he wanted printf or print as in printing 8-).

Comment: @slm Or just should install mailcap. On my system `man print` gives me a man page.

Comment: What man page is it? Formatted printing or something else?

Comment: mailcap on fedora doesn't include this man page.

Comment: It is installed with package `mime-support` on Ubuntu (12.04). `NAME run-mailcap,  view,  see,  edit, compose, print - execute programs via entries in the mailcap file`. Never seen it before, therefor my first thought was the OP meant `printf`

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about how to print from the command line the command you're looking for is usually `lpr` or `lp`. These are frontend tools for printing files from the command line.

- [lp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lp)
- [lpr man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lpr-cups)

**NOTE:** You can search the man pages using `-k` to search for keywords. If you'd done `man -k print` you would've found these pages.

To see what printers are available you can use `lpstat -a`, for example:

```
$ lpstat -a
brfax accepting requests since Wed 19 Jun 2013 06:20:02 PM EDT
Brother-MFC-4800 accepting requests since Wed 05 Jun 2013 01:35:48 PM EDT
Brother-MFC-J825DW accepting requests since Mon 17 Dec 2012 01:54:12 PM EST
mfc-8480dn accepting requests since Wed 19 Jun 2013 06:19:59 PM EDT
s820 accepting requests since Wed 19 Jun 2013 06:20:01 PM EDT
s820-scully accepting requests since Wed 19 Jun 2013 06:20:02 PM EDT
Stylus-NX300 accepting requests since Fri 08 Mar 2013 03:13:58 PM EST
```

To print to one of these printers I generally use the `lp` command like so:

```
$ lp -d mfc-8480dn sample.txt
request id is mfc-8480dn-454 (1 file(s))
```

To see what's in your print queue:

```
$ lpq -a
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
1st     saml    453     (stdin)                         0 bytes
active  saml    454     sample.txt                   1024 bytes
```

To remove a job from the print queue:

```
$ lprm 453
```

The print queue is now empty:

```
$ lpq -a
no entries
```

Comment: Good answer, but on a modern Linux system, I would expect the user to look for something more like [CUPS](http://cups.org/), which complicates matters even further.

Comment: @tripleee - these commands are just frontends. My entire backend is using CUPS. `lpr` is in fact part of the `cups` package. `rpm -qf /usr/bin/lpr` shows it's package as `cups-1.4.8-5.fc14.x86_64`.

Comment: Yeah, but it's a bit of a stretch to try to understand the printing system based on the documentation for a legacy front-end.